# Zurb Foundation: disable has-tooltip on mobile device

Tags: jquery, zurb-foundation

I've got a quick little question and I've only noticed one person with the same problem (but no solution)! I'm using Zurb's Foundation to create a responsive website. Foundation comes with a couple of usefull tools of which one is the Tooltip.

In a website I'm using the tooltip to tell a user what an icon is going to do when clicked. However! The tooltip is revealed upon mouseenter.. as we all know there is no real mouseenter event on a mobile device and this is where things go wrong. As a user clicks a filter button for example, he/she is not being served with the functionality of the button, but instead the tooltip shows.

So far not a real problem, usually with a hover/mouseenter action you simply click twice, but clicking twice does not solve the problem.

So.. the quick little question is: is there a way to disable the has-tooltip functionality? As I'm typing this I kind of think I found a solution.. so maybe there's no help needed,.. however. I can't be the only one having this problem now or in the future, so perhaps it's good to have the question asked!

Thanks for any help and if I find out an own solution, I'll comment below! :)

Comment: The thing I'm trying to do now is something like `$('.has-tip').not('.no-mobile-tip').tooltip();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could limit the call for the tooltip function depending on the `touch` property:

```
if($("html").hasClass("no-touch")) {
    $(document).foundationTooltips();
}
```

Comment: Let me try that.. somethings things are simpler as the solution you are looking for :-)

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks for the hint on the no-touch class in the html element! Will be needing that more than once in the future :-)

Answer (score 4):

There's also this:

```
$(document).foundation('tooltip', 'off');
```

via http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/javascript.html

Comment: That would still need in combination with the `.no-touch` class :) But thanks for the tip!

Comment: Yup, it would. But just another way... HTH

Comment: That was for v5 I think. In v6 it's: e.g. `Foundation.Tooltip.defaults.disableHover=false` before loading Foundation.

Answer (score 2):

Foundation 4 supports disabled feature for touch devises in data parameter.

```
data-options="disable-for-touch: true"
```

example:

```
<li id="print_button" class="has-tip" data-options="disable-for-touch: true" title="Print Take Five" class="none">
   <a href="">Print</a>
</li>
```

Source:

```
{
  selector : '.has-tip',
  additionalInheritableClasses : [],
  tooltipClass : '.tooltip',
  disable-for-touch: false,
  tipTemplate : function (selector, content) {
    return '<span data-selector="' + selector + '" class="'
      + Foundation.libs.tooltips.settings.tooltipClass.substring(1)
      + '">' + content + '<span class="nub"></span></span>';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that worked with Foundation 5.1.0 was:

`Foundation.libs.tooltip.settings.disable_for_touch = true;`